# How Can Take Integration of $exp(- \frac{t}{s}) * \frac{(a+c*m*t+c*u*z)}{s*(a+ r*m*t+r*u*z)} dt$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How could I simplify this equation and take integration? Could you please help me?

[image: Failed Integration]

```
Integrate[(E^(-(w/s)) h^(1 + L) (h + c m w + (c (-1 + m) z)/K)^-L)/(
 s (h + m r w + ((-1 + m) r z)/K)), {w, 0, Infinity}]
```

Comment: Try setting $L$ to small integers (both negative and positive) and see what you get.  And please make the title match the integrand in the text.

Answer (score 4):

$$
I=\int\frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}h^{1+L}\left(  h+cmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)
cz}{k}\right)  ^{-L}}{s\left(  h+cmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)  rz}{k}\right)
}dw
$$

One way to find the problem, is to simplify the integrad by removing stuff
that will not affect the result. Hence in the above, we can get rid of $s$ in
the denominator and get rid of $h^{1+L}$ in the numerator, since these are not
functions of $w$, this gives

$$
I=\frac{h^{1+L}}{s}\int\frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}\left(  h+cmw+\frac{\left(
m-1\right)  cz}{k}\right)  ^{-L}}{\left(  h+cmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)
rz}{k}\right)  }dw
$$

Also, $h+cmw+\frac{\left(  -1+m\right)  cz}{k}$ can be written as $a+cmw$
where $a=h+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)  cz}{k}$ since these are just parameters.
And similary, let $b=h+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)  rz}{k}$ This makes the integral

$$
I=\frac{h^{1+L}}{s}\int\frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}\left(  a+cmw\right)  ^{-L}
}{\left(  b+cmw\right)  }dw
$$

Which becomes

$$
I=\frac{h^{1+L}}{s}\int\frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}}{\left(  b+cmw\right)  \left(
a+cmw\right)  ^{L}}dw
$$

Let $cm=z$ then

$$
I=\frac{h^{1+L}}{s}\int\frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}}{\left(  b+zw\right)  \left(
a+zw\right)  ^{L}}dw
$$

And now we more easily see the problem. There does not seem to be
antiderivative for general $L$. When $b=a$, there is.

And now we more easily see the problem. There does not seem to be antiderivative for general $L$. When $b=a$, there is.

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, z, w, s, L]
Integrate[Exp[-w/s]/((a + z w) (b + z w)^L), w]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When $a=b$

```
 Integrate[Exp[-w/s]/((a + z w) (a + z w)^L), w]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When $L$ is specific value, it can also do it

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, z, w, w]
L = 3;
Integrate[Exp[-w/s]/((a + z w) (b + z w)^L), w]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think due to not being able to do factorization when $L$ is not given. But at least now it is more clear where the issue is.  There is no anti-derivative when $L$ does not have actual numerical value. I also tried Fricas which is supposed to have more complete Risch algorithm implementation and it can't do it for general $L$ either.

The integral pattern showing the problem can actually be simplified more to this form

$$
I=\int \frac{e^w}{\left(  b+ w\right)  \left(a+ w\right)  ^{L}}dw
$$

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but there is a mistake equation at the denominator.

$$
(h + c m w + \frac{(-1 + m)cz)}{K})^{-L}
$$

and
 
$$
s (h + m r w + \frac{(-1 + m)rz)}{K})
$$


So assumption is wrong. maybe series expansion uses.

Comment: @bilgeadam I fixed the typo. But it changes nothing in the final pattern, since these are all parameters and get absorbed  into $a,b$.

Comment: $$
I=\int\frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}h^{1+L}\left(  h+cmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)
cz}{k}\right)  ^{-L}}{s\left(  h+rmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)  rz}{k}\right)
}dw
$$

hi still there is a typo in denominator it's not "c m w" it should be "m r w" as above. It may not change the solution. 

Can we try the partial fraction decomposition method? What is your advice? 

Thank you.

Comment: I arranged equations as below. Can we try the partial fraction decomposition method? What would be your advice?
 $$
\int_{0}^{\propto} \frac{e^{-\frac{w}{s}}}{\left(\frac{h}{s\left(  h+rmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)  rz}{k}\right)}\right)\left(\frac{h}{ h+cmw+\frac{\left(  m-1\right)
cz}{k}}\right)  ^{L}}
$$
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@Nasser did all the heavy lifting.  I just started from the last equation and looked for patterns (using [OEIS](https://oeis.org) frequently).

Consider a few non-negative integer values of $L$ a pattern for

$$I=\int_0^\infty {{e^{-w}}\over{(b+w)(a+w)^L}}dw$$

```
TableForm[Table[{L, Integrate[Exp[-w]/((b + w) (a + w)^L), {w, 0, \[Infinity]},
  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]}, {L, 2, 4}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"L", "Integral"}}]
```

[image: Table of integrals for values of L]

It appears that there are polynomials in terms of $a$ and $a-b$ and the results can be constructed with 3 terms:

$$c_1 + c_2 e^a \text{Ei}(-a) + c_3 e^b \text{Ei}(-b)$$

with

$$c_1=\frac{\sum _{j=1}^{L-1} \frac{(-1)^j (L-1)! (a-b)^{j-1} a^{-j+L-2} \left(\sum _{i=0}^{j-1} (-1)^i i! a^{j-i}\right)}{j!}}{(L-1)! a^{L-1} (a-b)^{L-1}}$$

$$c_2=\frac{\sum _{i=0}^{L-1} (L-1)^{(i)} (b-a)^{-i+L-1}}{(L-1)! (a-b)^L}$$

$$c_3=-(a-b)^{-L}$$

or

```
c1 = (Sum[(a - b)^(j - 1) a^(L - 2 - j) (-1)^j Sum[i! (-1)^i a^(j - i), {i, 0, j - 1}] (L - 1)!/j!,
  {j, 1, L - 1}]/((L - 1)! a^(L - 1) (a - b)^(L - 1)) /. a - b -> z // FullSimplify) /. z -> a - b;
c2 = Sum[FactorialPower[L - 1, i] (b - a)^(L - 1 - i), {i, 0, L - 1}]/((L - 1)! (a - b)^L);
c3 = -(a - b)^-L;
```

Putting this altogether the integral is

```
c1 + c2 E^a ExpIntegralEi[-a] + c3 E^b ExpIntegralEi[-b]
```

For example, consider $L=9$:

```
L = 9;
integral1 = Integrate[Exp[-w]/((b + w) (a + w)^L), {w, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
integral2 = c1 + c2 E^a ExpIntegralEi[-a] + c3 E^b ExpIntegralEi[-b]
integral1 - integral2 // Together
(* 0 *)
```